# How do I modify the value of a dict in the form of "Dictionary<string, (float r , float g , float b )>"?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I was trying to modify a value inside my `mCurrentSprite` dictionary. The Problem is I get a error when I try to modify or set it by accessing it through the key string `mPartName`. How can this be fixed?

```
mCurrentSprite[mPartName].r -= 0.1f;
```

> Error code: Cannot modify the return value of `Dictionary<string, (float r, float g, float b)>.this[string]` because it is not a
> variable

Comment: Could you please add the error to your question?

Comment: `(float r, float g, float b)` is a value tuple. The dictionary stores a copy of the entire value. If you want to change it, you must pass a new tuple into the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, (float r, float g, float b)>` with a value tuple as the value. The dictionary actually returns a copy of the value for value types.  So, you could use a temp variable to change the value and you'll need to assign the whole key as a tuple:

```
if(mCurrentSprite.TryGetValue(mPartName, out var tuple))
{
    mCurrentSprite[mPartName] = (tuple.r - 0.1f, tuple.g, tuple.b);
}
```

---

ValueTuples are actually mutable, demonstrated in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9WFTN). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple) state:

> - `System.ValueTuple` types are value types. `System.Tuple` types are
>   reference types.
> - `System.ValueTuple` types are **mutable**. `System.Tuple`
>   types are **immutable**.
> - Data members of `System.ValueTuple` types are
>   fields. Data members of `System.Tuple` types are properties.

So, the above could be re-written as:

```
if(mCurrentSprite.TryGetValue(mPartName, out var tuple))
{
    tuple.r = tuple.r - 0.1f;
    mCurrentSprite[mPartName] = tuple;
}
```

Comment: TIL that I can name the parts of a tuple: TY